# Does using different Analysis Methods give the same better alternative to choose between economic projects?

Tags: mathematical-economics, interest-rate, financial-economics, real-analysis

Will all analysis methods (PW-FW-AW-ROR-B/C) that we can use for determining project acceptability on an economic basis gives you the correct same-alternative for the same cash-flow always?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the question is asking: are the statements PW(A)>PW(B), FW(A)>FW(B), AW(A)>AW(B), ROR(A)>ROR(B), B/C(A)>B/C(B) all equivalent?